# C++ what is the most efficient ways to shuffle an array inside a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, shuffle

I need to shuffle a 2d array that is inside of a struct. Can anyone explain the most efficient way to do this?

```
struct arrstruct {
    char grid[4][4] = { { 'a','b','c','d' },
                        { 'e','f','g','h' },
                        { 'a','b','c','d' },
                        { 'e','f','g','h' } };
};
```

The reason the array is in the struct is because it's also part of a function and this was the way I found to return the values correctly. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my shuffle function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter (for the shuffling) that it's 2D, and it doesn't matter that it's inside a struct. What you're doing with the `struct` is to reinvent `std::array`.

Comment: You also need to clarify what shuffle for a 2D array is supposed to be: per row, per column, the entire matrix, or what?

Comment: It helps to define what you mean by "efficient" there are actually multiple kinds of efficiency. Assuming you just mean algorithmic, it makes little difference that it is inside a struct. You also should be specific in what you mean by "it doesn't work."

Comment: What is your shuffle function btw?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question in this forum and my first class.

Comment: id shuffle() {
 srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
 random_shuffle(&deck[0][0], &deck[0][0] + 4 * 4);
 for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
 }
}

Comment: @Jagged: You should not recommend reseeding the random number generator in a shuffle function.

Comment: Ok, this isn't coming out the way I expected.... that was supposed to be my shuffle function. Since I put the array in the struct, it gives me an error that "deck" is undefined. As far as efficient goes, it doesn't matter it was just a choice in words.. it just needs to work.

Comment: So shuffling should be done in main?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "shuffle".

However, assuming you want to shuffle the 16 characters in your array .... since C++11 you can use;

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
      arrstruct astruct;

      char *first = &astruct.grid[0][0];

      std::random_device rd;
      std::mt19937 g(rd());

      std::shuffle(first, first + 16, g);
}
```

Note the above relies on a 2D array being contiguous, and has hard-coded the number of elements (`16`).

If you want to shuffle the four rows, but leave the contents of each row intact, it is easier.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::shuffle(std::begin(arrstruct.grid), std::end(arrstruct.grid), g);
```

Before C++11, you can use `std::random_shuffle()`, but bear in mind it was deprecated and removed from later versions of the C++ standard due to dubious properties.

`std::shuffle()`'s complexity is linear in the number of entitles being shuffled.